# The array is not Shuffling what is the mistake in the Code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, shuffle

```
  function shuffleArray() {
    let array=characters
    for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
      const temp = array[i];
      array[i] = array[j];
      array[j] = temp;
    }
    setCharacters(array)
  }
```

The array is not shuffling and not triggering an re-render and the it's an array of images

Comment: What does your array look like? Input and expected output would be useful.

Comment: What is `characters`? The shuffling is perfectly fine. If you don't see any effect, the error has to be somewhere in the code you are not showing us.

Answer (score 0):

worked fine for me when I tried to replicate your code...

```
function shuffleArray() {
  let array=['c', 'h', 'a', 'r']
  for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    const temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
  }
  return array
}

console.log(shuffleArray())
```

[Working pen here](https://codepen.io/pen/?editors=0011)

Answer (score 0):

The error might not be the shuffling, which works fine, but your usage of it in react.

When you do

```
array = characters;
```

you are not copying the array, but just assigning `array` to point to the very same reference of that array, ie `array === characters` returns `true`.

Thus, when you finally do

```
setCharacters(array);
```

react may not pick up on the changed array (because it's pointing to the same reference) and thus doesn't rerender the component.

Try making a shallow copy of your `characters` array with `slice()` and reassign the state after the shuffling

```
function shuffleArray() {
  let array = characters.slice();
  for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    const temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
  }
  setCharacters(array)
}
```